# Viability of a "dungeon" tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I just posted [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/32515/6986) on the main site. While I was looking over the tags, I noticed that none of them really fit my question. I've selected three tags that are related, but don't really capture the essence of what I'm asking.

There have been several questions about RPG-esque adventurers in a world, and I'm sure there will be more, not to mention any questions about specific features of a dungeon(s) a character(s) has to explore.

Would it make sense to create a "dungeon" tag to cover above- or below-ground locations, including any traps, pitfalls, and other detritus likely to appear therein?

Comment: It does seem like it would be a useful tag, I've tried to think of a reason to oppose it but I've refuted all of my own arguments.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I'll wait a while longer to see if there's any opposition, then create it this afternoon if there isn't, I suppose.

Comment: I would also like to point out that [it should be 'dungeons'](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/tags-cleaning-singular-vs-plural)

Comment: You can also rely on the natural tag development: if only one question has it, it will disappear. If it does not pick up on a longer term, it would probably get cleaned.